# Why Android emulator 29.2.0 crashes when running under Gnu/Linux?

Tags: android, android-emulator

Today (2019-09-20) I updated my android emulator to version 29.2.0. After the install I couldn't initialize it. It always return the error:

`Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: Emulator update has been released in the stable channel. So this problem is now fixed.

After searching through stackoverflow, I couldn't find anything about that.

Then I tried on Google and also couldn't find anything. Just when checking the release notes of Android Emulator 29.2.1 Canary (https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2019/09/emulator-2921-canary.html), I noticed an entry which shed some light:

`Fixed crash on startup on Linux Wayland systems.`

And the problem seems to be some interaction with XkbGetKeyboard and Wayland. There is no workaround I could find but the next stable version will have the fix. Obviously you can try the Canary version 29.2.1.

So, just wanted to let this problem registered here in case anyone face this problem and looks for a clue about what the problem is.

I hope it helps.

Comment: I got the same on Arch + Wayland, and it was resolved by installing `android-emulator-canary` (29.1.12-1) in place of `android-emulator`(29.2.0-1)

Answer (score 0):

today, 2019-9-24, exactly the same issue